# How to create window next to current one in GNU screen?

Tags: gnu, gnu-screen

I want to change to the new window with `C-a n`. So How to create window next to current one in GNU screen?

If GNU screen can not do that, is there a alternative recommended?

Answer (score 0):

GNU screen can do that like this:
`C-a :split -v`

See this section of the documentation for more details: 
https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Regions